# When do Lava and Kusha sing the song in Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, rama

In the Ramayana of Ramanand Sagar, there are only 3 Events when Lava and Kusha meet Shri Rama. First when they have sung the song in Ayodhya, and after the fight against Lord Rama.

In the last episode of Ramayana, both Lava and Kusha come to Ayodhya, and sing [Hum Katha Sunate Ram Sakal Lyrics](https://www.dailybhajan.com/ram-bhajan-lyrics/hum-katha-sunate-ram-sakal-lyrics), and while singing this last bhajan of Ramayana, Sita Mata goes into Earth and disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Lava-kusha meet shri ram in sarga-4 of balakand and say the katha of rama.

Valmiki composed twenty four thousand verses and taught them to Lava and Kusha, the sons of Rama and Seetha. The two youngsters sing the ballad among the assemblages of sages and saints, and win laurels. Rama on seeing the boys singing on the streets and king's ways of Ayodhya, brings them to his palace, and summons all his brothers and ministers to listen to the ballad. Rama himself is put to the turmoil, for the ballad sung by these youngsters narrates the legend of Seetha. But he himself collecting his calm, Rama paid his attention to listen the 'Legend of Seetha' siithaayaH charitam mahat as Valmiki calls Ramayana.